# Issue with the Prepared Stetement Parameter when injecting Single Parameter in Select Query

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to create the prepared statement for the select query

```
String Select_Query = "select * from customers where customerNumber=? ";
Connection connection = DriverManagersSQL.getDriverMangerInstance();
preparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(Select_Query);
statement.setInt(1, 101);
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(Select_Query);
```

But I am having one error like this :

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

I ran the query into the database and its working fine. There is no syntax error. This happens with me all the time when I try to use with single filtering parameter. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you should be passing the SQL again the `executeQuery`. You've set up the statement already, so you should just call `executeQuery()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call

```
statement.executeQuery(Select_Query)
```

You've already set up your PreparedStatement. It's already got your SQL and the parameters that go in it.

Just call

```
statement.executeQuery()
```

instead.

[executeQuery()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) is a method of PreparedStatement that will perform the query you already gave it, using the parameters you have already set.

[executeQuery(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) is a method of Statement which tries to execute the query you are giving it now. It does not use your parameters, and the docs specifically say that if you call this method on a PreparedStatement it will cause an SQLException.

Comment: That works. Thanks. @khelwood